# The asset path of image not set

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I already created a path of my image and when I am using it in pubsec.yaml file it shows me error which you can see in a image which I have attached with this. For this problem I deleted the previous and make a new path but again it shows me same error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXdfo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

did you add it to your `pubspec.yaml` file ?

try adding the folder like this

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - images/
```

pay attention to the spaces it should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to create an assets folder in your project root directory if you haven't already then create images folder and then you need to define that folder to your assets in pubsec.yaml like this

```
 assets:
  - assets/images/
```

then copy your images to this images folder inside your directory and use it like

```
Image.asset(
    'images/yourimage.jpg'
    )
```

Comment: Sorry bro but that's not the solution it's some spelling error I resolved it by myself. BTW thanks for your solution.

Comment: @Harshitrai Great bro..you are always welcomed to support and helping our developer community, have a good day. :)